# Import @Configuration in runtime

Tags: java, spring, configuration

Let's say I have 2 spring @Configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
public class Config1 {
   @Bean
   public SomeInterface getSomeInterface() {
      return SomeImpl1;
   }
}


@Configuration
public class Config2 {
   @Bean
   public SomeInterface getSomeInterface() {
      return SomeImpl2;
   }
}
```

Usually in my root context class I would do something like this:

```
@Import(Config1.class)
@Configuration
public class RootConfig {
   ...
}
```

Of course, I could do the same with `Config2`.

But what if I would like to choose which of them to load on runtime and not using `@Import`. Something like:

```
@Configuration
public class RootConfig {
   @DynamicImports // Made-up annotation
   public void loadConfigs() {
      // Do some logic here that imports Config1 or Config2 dynamically by some parameters (for example, env param)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Profile` at configuration class level:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DevConfig {
}

@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
public class ProdConfig {
}
```

Then you can activate your current profile in different ways. For example inside a test class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class DevIntegrationTest
```

In this case you are setting current active profile to dev and only `@Profile("dev")` annotated class are loaded.

You can also set current active profile setting a parameter to jvm:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="dev"
```

So continue to using your `@Import`, but only class with correct profile will be loaded.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with this solution. Actually this question was just raised in a tech-talk in which I explained about `@Configuration` and that's the answer I gave. But I wonder if there's a way to do it with a simple `if`. There's something in profiles that people don't like usually. It's less clear.

Comment: @Avi I dont know, but maybe using Configuration classes is not possible. I'm interested in your question, so I'll wainting for a guru answer :) Maybe looking at this source code could be useful: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassParser.java

Comment: Let's wait and see if a guru answers :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you can do it only manually, when you have the reference to context. For example:

```
var diContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
diContext.register(FirstConfig.class);
diContext.register(SecondConfig.class);
...
```

Another way is to create config class at runtime, as it is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64896409/5057736).